# Atmel AVR Assembler time stamp counter

Tags: assembly, avr, atmel, atmega

Good day, everyone! 
I try to randomize numbers on AVR Asm (atmega128). So I need initialize value at the beginning and note that for asm x86 developers use "rdtsc" instruction. Is that possible to init some random init value like rdtsc at AVR architecture? Is that possible to use different init value?
Thanks and regards.

Comment: Maybe have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864668/is-it-possible-to-generate-random-numbers-using-physical-sensors/10871077#10871077 for some ways to obtain random numbers and/or seeds for PRNGs. For your case (one-time seed generation), using un-initialized RAM seems to be viable.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a timer that is running off the CPU clock (because that is what the TSC is). That said, this is only sufficient for seeding a pseudo random number generator, and the generated random numbers are not suitable for cryptographic operations.

Comment: If you can explain how to get cpu time, please do it.

Comment: It is not really CPU time -- the counters on AVR however run with a clock derived from the CPU clock. The main difference to the TSC on x86 is that the TSC register is longer and does not overflow.

Comment: Also I have idea to save random number to eeprom, and then get it from there. But it can be slow, I scare.

Comment: Saving and restoring random seeds is good if you want to avoid repetitions (this is something you'd use in a game, for example). Your random number generator should be adapted to your application.

Comment: You are right, I can save and restore current random number from eeprom to prevent repetition, but I want avoid using eeprom. If don't do it, every reset of microcontroller give the same set of random numbers.

Comment: I think you want a mixture of both -- EEPROM storage so your PRNG is seeded with more than 16 bits of state, and something unpredictable from the hardware (timer or ADC). Be aware that this is still not sufficient for cryptography.

Answer (score 0):

I see, you know it, but to emphasize once again, you can't use any timer/counter value as random number generator. You can use it only as a **source for the pseudo random algorithm seed number.**

In order to do it, you need a timer/counter that counts fast and continuously and human that actually performs as a random event generator.

Without human interaction, it is not possible to get random number seed using timer or counter.

In the computers, the human randomizes the moment of the program start.

The counter is not actually so important. The only requirement to it is to run much more faster then the human reaction time. Several kilohertz is a acceptable frequency. This way, you can use for example some of the timers, configured to the fastest possible frequency, or even a simple software counter incremented on every main program loop (of course if the program is fast enough).

If your device supports real time clock, use it. This way you will get better randomization, because the RTC runs even if the whole devide is switched off.

This way, the human provided switch ON will provide random moment event.

In all cases, the algorithm that you will use to generate the pseudo random numbers is much more important than the seed generation approach.

So, make is as simple and stupid as possible and concentrate on the pseudo random number generator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use atmega128 and only need a source of random algorithm (Linear congruential generator). Before the moment I fill source, there's no human interaction, so it's useless to work with timer. Also atmega128 have no real time clock. If I'm wrong, correct me.

Comment: @IvanVavilov You are right, if there is no human interaction, using timers and counters is useless. There are many random number generator algorithms out there. Even look at wikipedia for such examples. BTW, you can try to use the ADC convertor of ATMega, connected to some white noise generator in order to get true random numbers (although I suppose most good pseudo random number generators will give you better distribution). It all depends on the your project destination.